# html5 change background image interval time

Tags: javascript

How can i change body background image at interval time, for example, every 10 seconds should change the background image.
it is possible with html5?
Thanks

Comment: This is nothing to do with html5 or even css3 - it's just plain old javascript. How people love buzzwords.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a javascript function for this and use the SetTimeOut in that function itself which will call the same function after the specified time interval.

Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds){
    //change the image
    if(!imageID){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.all-freeware.com/images/full/38943-nice_feathers_free_screensaver_desktop_screen_savers__nature.jpeg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else{if(imageID==1){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.hickerphoto.com/data/media/186/flower-bouquet-nice_12128.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }else{if(imageID==2){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg";
        imageID=0;
    }}}
    //call same function again for x of seconds
    setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
}
</script>
</head>

<body style='background:black;' onload='changeimage(2)'>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='center'><img width='300px' height='250px' id='myimage' src='http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg'/></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and how can i use the opacity, when the image get change??

Comment: As i have described above that i am using a function to change the image. You can define opacity in the body part from where function is being called.

Answer (score 1):

Just by setting document.body.backgroundImage.

You can do this in a function that is called by either setInterval or setTimeout.